# Passing Variables into GraphQL Query in Gatsby

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I want to limit the number of posts fetched on my index page. Currently, the number of pages is hard-coded into the GraphQL query.

```
query {
    allMarkdownRemark(limit: 5, sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to replace "5" with the value of a variable. String interpolation will not work with the `graphql` function, so I have to use another method.

Is there a way to achieve this and pass variables into a GraphQL query in GatsbyJS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only pass variables to GraphQL query via context since string interpolation doesn't work in that way. In [page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/page-query/#how-to-add-query-variables-to-a-page-query) (rather than static queries) you can pass a variable using the `context` object as an argument of [`createPage` API](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/actions/#createPage). So, you'll need to add this page creation to your `gatsby-node.js` and use something like:

```
const limit = 10;

page.forEach(({ node }, index) => {
  createPage({
    path: node.fields.slug,
    component: path.resolve(`./src/pages/index.js`), // your index path
    // values in the context object are passed in as variables to page queries
    context: {
      limit: limit,
    },
  })
})
```

Now, you have in your `context` object a `limit` value with all the required logic behind (now it's a simple number but you can add there some calculations). In your `index.js`:

```
query yourQuery($limit: String) {
    allMarkdownRemark(limit: $limit, sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
```